# mysql node returning unwanted results

Tags: mysql, node.js

node beginner here, but experienced with javascript.

I'm executing this query in node mysql, along with the `promise-mysql` package. The objective is to insert a new user if not exists, and get the user data afterwards.

```
SET @email = ?;
INSERT IGNORE INTO users 
(id,email, first_name, last_name,fb_user_id) 
VALUES (0,@email,?,?,?);
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = @email;
```

Example usage, where `sql` is the query above.

```
return db.query(sql,[email,first_name,last_name,fbUserId])
    .then((results)=>{
        console.log(results)
        return results;
    })
```

The `results` object looks like this

```
[ OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 10,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 },
  OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 10,
    warningCount: 1,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 },
  [ RowDataPacket {
      id: 98,
      email: 'surfinchicken@gmail.com',
      first_name: 'Bob',
      last_name: 'Law',
      fb_user_id: 10203453461607024 } ] ]
```

JSON version:

```
[{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":10,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0},{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":10,"warningCount":1,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0},[{"id":98,"email":"surfinchicken@gmail.com","first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Law","fb_user_id":10203453461607024 }]]
```

What are these `OkPacket`s? Why can't i get a simple array of the data, instead of this meta data. Do i have to do `var user = results[2][0]`??. Please tell me what i am missing, because these arguments seem wrong. There's no way i should have to manually parse this argument for every query i'll eventually write..

Comment: You are executing 3 sql statements and you get the results for each of the statements.  This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Do you have any suggestions on how to cut these 3 statements into 1?

Comment: You cannot combine an insert and a select into one.